# What does this JavaScript expression mean: return 0==a?!1:void 0==a.x?

Tags: javascript

This is part of a very long return statement, but I was more interested in understanding what the "a?!1:void0" stood for.

I came across it when I was inspecting a webpage trying to figure out how it was functioning as far as its javascript code was concerned.

EDIT: From comments below, I have gathered that I have written the exact question poorly. Initially I was trying to simplify "return 0==a?!1:void 0==a.x" to "a?!1:void 0" -- in order to indicate that I was confused in particular about that segment of the statement. But thinking back, it does not make sense to do so, because in effect I am changing the meaning of the conditional.

Also the "?" at the end, is an English question mark as @Amadan has pointed out.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: It returns false if var a is true and void if it isn't

Comment: @RobG returns `false` - not `1`

Comment: @Eihwaz—there is no "void" value, `void0` returns *undefined* regardless of the expression that follows it (see [*EMCA-262 §12.5.5*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-void-operator)).

Comment: @RobG Exactly, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void, void is there to return undefined, my statement is still valid, as well as yours.

Comment: @Eihwaz: It is not. You cannot return void, as that is not a value, but an operator. Returning `void` makes as much sense as returning a `typeof`.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. The expression in the title is quite different to the one in the body of the post. Some have responded to one part, others to the other part.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the operation (0==a)? !1:(void 0==a.x)
void 0 can be conceived as void(0), which is nothing but undefined.
If a.x is undefined, 
!1 is equal to false.
(void 0==a.x) is equal to true. 
so the expression evaluates to (0==a)? false:true.

May be it could have been a generated code, not sure why should one write the logic so.

Answer (score 0):

Equal to,

```
if (a) {//return true if a is truthy
  return !1;// !1 is always false, !0 is true
}else{ 
  return void(0);//void(0) is undefined
}
```

Comment: That should be "*return true if a is truthy*", i.e. any value that coerces to true, such as number other than 0 and NaN, non–empty string, any Object, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It returns `true` if `a.x` is defined; `false` if `a` is falsy or `a.x` is undefined. It is equivalent to

```
if (!a) { // !a === (a == 0)
  return false; // false === !1
} else if (a.x == undefined) { // undefined === void 0
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

Comment: We don't know what is returned after `void 0==a.x?`. The second part is "if a.x == undefined" … something : something. The something part isn't known.

Comment: @RobG: I think "?" at the end of the title is not JavaScript, but English (plain old question mark, not an operator).

Comment: Ok, there are two issues here: it's a poorly asked question and the code itself is too clever for its own good. The body of a question should stand alone, without the title. And `0==a` has some quirks, as does `void 0 == a.x`. An alternative might be `a || !a.x`, which doesn't cure any of the quirks but if the intention was to save a few characters, it fails at that too.

Comment: @RobG: I do not disagree. :)

Comment: Actually, an equivalent is `a && !!a.x`.

Comment: @RobG: Almost-equivalent. It is not equivalent when `a.x` is falsy but not `null` or `undefined` (e.g. `a.x == "0"`). Still, close enough for most purposes.